# How to find a rigid motion that rotate the plane $5z+3x+4y =5$ to $z+x=1$ around the $z$- axis

Tags: differential-geometry, vectors

I see this in a solution of exercise as the first step but I am not sure is this really legitimate.

I was thinking of a rigid motion that maps the span of the tangent plane of $5z+3x+4y=5$ to that of $z+x=1$ which I now know is not the correct way, the correct way should be mapping the normal to another normal by realizing the standard matrix of the rotation around $z$ axis and reverse engineer to compute the $\theta$

Comment: Find the unit normals to both planes, and then rotate one to the other around the $z$ axis.

Comment: can someone give me the standard matrix,I am really stucked

Answer (score 1):

Knowing that the [Rotation matrix around the $z$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Basic_rotations) axis can be written as  $$\begin{bmatrix}
 \cos\theta  &-\sin\theta  & 0 \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta  & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $$
Where $\theta $  is the angle of rotation. Thus if you want to rotate your plane, it is enough to rotate its normal. Let  $n_1$ be the unit normal of your plane, and let $n_2$ be the unit normal of the obtained plane after rotation. Then to find the rigid motion that rotates your plane, enough to find the angle of rotation $ \theta$ that rotates $n_1$ to  $n_2$. Translating this into a pracrical form we may write
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
 \cos\theta  &-\sin\theta  & 0 \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta  & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} n_1= n_2 $$
$n_1$ and  $n_2$ are known, so expanding the above you would get a system of equations of two unkowns $ \sin\theta$  and  $\cos \theta$. Try to find  $\theta$ and you are done.

Comment: You are a genius. I finally know what is going on, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

After rotation, the new coordinates will be

$$x'=x\cos\theta-y\sin\theta\\y'=x\sin\theta+y\cos\theta\\z'=z.$$

Plugging in the new equation,

$$z+x\cos\theta-y\sin\theta=1$$ must be the same as the original equation, which is

$$z+\frac35x+\frac45y=1.$$

By identification, $$\cos\theta=\frac35,\sin\theta=-\frac45,$$

which are compatible.

Comment: Where is the line $z+xcosθ−ysinθ=1$ comes from?

Comment: I see it, thanks